# jQuery reload the DOM?

Tags: jquery, dom

I have a page that has a button on it. When the user clicks the button it dynamically render's a form (ie it's not just showing a hidden form.. it's completely creating it using jQuery).

My issue is the newly created form doesn't respond to any jQuery commands. This is the code I have for the rendered form at the moment.

```
$("#savenewlang").click(function(e) {
    console.log("savenewlang has been clicked");
});
```

So it should just console.log when they click the submit button but it's not running.

Any idea how to reload the DOM or assign that an actual event that correctly fires?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$("#container").on('click', '#savenewlang', function(e) {
    console.log("savenewlang has been clicked");
});
```

Here `#container` points to a parent element of `#savenewlang` that belongs to DOM at page load.

---

To specify this event `.on()` you need ***three arguments***

```
.on(eventName, target, callback);
```

But for ordinary binding it only needs ***two arguments***

```
.on(eventName, callback);
```

Read more about **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)**

---

#### Remainder

Put all of your code within

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

in short

```
$(function() {

});
```

Comment: This worked great, however I should note that it won't work unless you include it in the $(document).ready(). (Obvious) but I had it wrong first go around.

Answer (score 6):

Basically whats happening is that when you add content to the dom dynamically, you will have to manually attach handlers to the added dom elements. However if you use the jquery on() function, you can create persistent event handlers. Using the fact that events bubble up in the dom, when someone clicks on your dynamic dom element, which has no event handler for click, the event will bubble up to the body element, where the on() function will determine that the actual item clicked was #savenewlang, and then call the function(e){} that you defined.

```
$("body").on('click', '#savenewlang', function(e) {
    console.log("savenewlang has been clicked");
});
```

syntax would be:

```
$('#selector_or_id_of_static_element').on('event_type','#selector_for dynamic_content', function(e){ //callback});
```

Comment: sorry was just about to add some notes

Answer (score 0):

The event handler is being added when the DOM element doesn't exist yet. You could try putting it in a function:

```
function addEvent() {
    $("#savenewlang").click(function(e) {
        console.log("savenewlang has been clicked");
    });
}
```

Now call this function after you have dynamically added the form.

Answer (score 0):

Since the elements are rendered dynamically, you'll need to use the .delegate() method top assign the function, like this:

```
$("body").delegate("#savenewlang", "click", function(e) {
    console.log("savenewlang has been clicked");
});
```

See the reference for more info: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: From the documentation: *As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.*.

Comment: @blender does superseded mean it is going to be removed any time soon? we know .live will not exist in 1.8, but i'm pretty sure .delegate will exist in 1.8 and going forward.

Comment: Supersede means to take the place of. I'm sure it will be removed eventually, but even if that date isn't explicitly given, is it really that hard to use `.on()`?

Comment: @Blender thanks for pointing out, I forgot to mention the .on() method.